# How to loop over a filter column & copy past the result

Tags: excel, vba

So i'm stuck, i want loop over a a filter column A & copy past the result of filtered result for example column B & C then copy past it in another file that i created & opened
so here my result but it open the file but copy nothing

```
/`
Sub TepHebdo()
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim n As Long

For i = 1 To 14 Step 1
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\arabw\Desktop\vba\StatTech\tech" & i & ".xlsx")
Next

' Loop sur les filtres

For n = 1 To uniquesArray
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AX$1547").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=uniquesArray(n, 1)
    Columns("N:P").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("tech" & n & ".xlsx").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Windows("Suivi.xlsm").Activate
Next


'------------------------------------------------------------


Workbooks("tech1.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech2.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech3.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech4.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech5.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech6.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech7.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech8.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech9.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech10.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech11.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech12.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech13.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
Workbooks("tech14.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True


End Sub`
```

Any help please :) ? Ty

Comment: What is `uniquesArray`?

Comment: Maybe `For n = 1 To UBound(uniquesArray,1)`

Comment: The VBA script keeps in the same workbook, even if another Excel window has the focus. Thus each workbook has to be accessed by open them with `wb(i)=`